# Using constants in MySQL DDL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to use constants in MySQL DDL statements (e.g. CREATE TABLE...)

This would be handy to avoid hardcoding repetitive field lengths, to keep consistency between primary and foreign keys, etc.

I've tried using variables, e.g.

```
SET  @flength = 4;
CREATE TABLE test (
    serial VARCHAR(@flength)
)
```

But apparently this is not supported.

Comment: What makes you think its not supported, as if you have checked the manual and it says this is not allowed have you not answered your own question?

Comment: Well, I've tried, and it fails with "Syntax error". I've done my homework searching before asking this community, and I could find nothing of the sort.